# "What" and "which" difference

Tags: grammar

**What or which** : which one should be used?

- **What/which** medicine is good for boosting immunity of children?
- **What/which** is the longest river in the world?

I think both are correct. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

***Which*** is used when there is some defined set of possible answers.

***What*** is used when there is not such a set.

Where the set is very large, either may be acceptable. Both of your examples are very large sets, unless the context restricts that set in some way.

Comment: When the set is undefined can ”which” safely replace “what”?

Comment: If there's a set that someone could sit down and make, even if it would take a very long time, you can use *which*. So all the medicines in the world is such a set, all the stars in the sky are such a set, and so on. If you have to infer what the set it completely, it's not. So, "what would you like for dinner", if there's no options implied by context (or even if there is), but "which would you like for dinner" *requires* context to indicate what the set of options is. "Which meal would you like for dinner" works semantically even without that context, but is not idiomatic without it.

Comment: if the context has been introduced and we know that there is a strictly defined set of possible options, can we use "what"? (even if we know that "which" would be more natural)

Comment: You *can* use what, but in that context it makes it seem more informal.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I would say:

> **Which** medicine is good for boosting immunity of children?
>
> **Which** is the longest river in the world?